# How to print two bmp into two different pages?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pdf, printing, panel

The way I'm trying is generating two overlapping images.

I could make two different buttons to print two separate bmp, but I need the two bmp are printed on the same page as the user can choose the PDF printer and generate a two-page file.

```
void Imprimir()
{
    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
    pd.DocumentName = "Relatório SisIndice";
    pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(doc_PrintPage);
    pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
    PrintDialog printDialog1 = new PrintDialog();
    printDialog1.Document = pd;
    DialogResult result = printDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {    
        pd.Print();
    }
}

private void doc_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pnlPrint.Width, pnlPrint.Height, pnlPrint.CreateGraphics());
    pnlPrint.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, pnlPrint.Width, pnlPrint.Height));
    RectangleF bounds = e.PageSettings.PrintableArea;
    float factor = ((float)bmp.Height / (float)bmp.Width);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, bounds.Left, bounds.Top, 1118, 855);
    e.HasMorePages = true;
    Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(dgvDetGraf.Width, dgvDetGraf.Height, dgvDetGraf.CreateGraphics());
    dgvDetGraf.DrawToBitmap(bmp1, new Rectangle(0, 1800, dgvDetGraf.Width, dgvDetGraf.Height));
    RectangleF bounds1 = e.PageSettings.PrintableArea;
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp1, bounds1.Left, bounds1.Top, 894, 684);
    e.HasMorePages = false;

}
```

Comment: What is the error? And where

Comment: In printing out the images on one another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close but you missed that the `PrintPage` event fires for a single page. In that event you have to do all the painting/drawing on its `Graphics` object. When there are no more pages you set `HasMorePages` to false.

So instead of drawing all those bitmaps at once you have to keep track if you are on page 1 or page 2 and based on that Draw the bitmap that you want on that page.

I've chosen the simplest solution that might work that involves a `page` variable to keep track of the page we're on.

```
int page = 0; 

void Imprimir()
{
    // snip irrelevant stuf
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {   
        // reset our state to page 1
        page = 1;
        pd.Print();
    }
}

private void doc_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    // this gets called twice, the page variable
    // keeps track of what to do (it keeps the State)
    switch(page)
    {
        // do this for page 1
        case 1:
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pnlPrint.Width, pnlPrint.Height, pnlPrint.CreateGraphics());
            pnlPrint.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, pnlPrint.Width, pnlPrint.Height));
            RectangleF bounds = e.PageSettings.PrintableArea;
            float factor = ((float)bmp.Height / (float)bmp.Width);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, bounds.Left, bounds.Top, 1118, 855);
            e.HasMorePages = true;
            break;
        // do this for page 2
        case 2:
            Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(dgvDetGraf.Width, dgvDetGraf.Height, dgvDetGraf.CreateGraphics());
            dgvDetGraf.DrawToBitmap(bmp1, new Rectangle(0, 1800, dgvDetGraf.Width, dgvDetGraf.Height));
            RectangleF bounds1 = e.PageSettings.PrintableArea;
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp1, bounds1.Left, bounds1.Top, 894, 684);
            e.HasMorePages = false;
            break;
    }
    // don't forget to go the next state ... 
    page++; // increase page counter
}
```

Comment: thank you so much rene. It did work perfectly! Regards!